create several dummy variables in dplyr base on a range
Unfortunately, I could not find a suitable simple solution.
Suppose I have a dataframe like this
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:20, value = sample(20))
ranges <- c(0, 5, 10, 15)

I want to create a dummy variable for each successive range, as in the following example:
data %>% mutate(dummy_0_5= if_else(value >= ranges[1] & value < ranges[2] , 1,0), 
dummy_5_10 =  if_else(value >= ranges[2] & value < ranges[3] , 1,0)).

The next dummies should be between ranges[3] and ranges[4].
However, ranges could be stored in other ways (df, list, vector, etc). The most important feature for me is that I want to test different ranges, so I don't want to adjust the column name each time I switch to the correct ranges.

Assuming that you need only three dummy groups, and leaving those value >= 15 (I set it to NA) , a solution could be using cut to create a dummy factor and binding data to table output:
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:20, value = sample(20))

library(dplyr)
data<-data %>% 
mutate(dummy=cut(value, breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15), labels = FALSE,  right = F))

data<-cbind(data %>% arrange(value),with(data, table(value, dummy)) %>%
      as.data.frame.matrix()) %>% 
      rename(dummy_0_5=c(4), dummy_5_10 = c(5), dummy_10_15 = c(6))

data
   ID value dummy dummy_0_5 dummy_5_10 dummy_10_15
1   3     1     1         1          0           0
2   4     2     1         1          0           0
3  10     3     1         1          0           0
4   1     4     1         1          0           0
5  12     5     2         0          1           0
6  15     6     2         0          1           0
7   2     7     2         0          1           0
8  20     8     2         0          1           0
9  13     9     2         0          1           0
10 18    10     3         0          0           1
11  7    11     3         0          0           1
12 17    12     3         0          0           1
13  5    13     3         0          0           1
14  9    14     3         0          0           1
15 16    15    NA         0          0           0
16 14    16    NA         0          0           0
17  8    17    NA         0          0           0
18 11    18    NA         0          0           0
19  6    19    NA         0          0           0
20 19    20    NA         0          0           0


Thanks so much. Helped me a lot. especially the cut function. I guess an alternative to avoid a little the second part would by data %>%    mutate(dummy_name=cut(value, breaks = ranges, labels = paste(ranges[-1]),  right = F),          dummy = 1) %>%    pivot_wider(.,  names_from =dummy_name,               values_from = dummy,                 values_fill = 0, names_glue = "dummy_{dummy_name}") %>%    select(-ends_with("_NA"))

We could also do a join and pivot, like:
library(tidyverse)
data |>
  left_join(data.frame(from = ranges, to = coalesce(lead(ranges), Inf)),
            join_by(value >= from, value < to)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(from, to), values_fn = ~1, values_fill = 0) |>
  right_join(data) # optional, to bring values back in

Result
      ID `0_5` `5_10` `10_15` `15_Inf` value
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1      0       0        0     4
 2     2     0      1       0        0     7
 3     3     1      0       0        0     1
 4     4     1      0       0        0     2
 5     5     0      0       1        0    13
 6     6     0      0       0        1    19
 7     7     0      0       1        0    11
 8     8     0      0       0        1    17
 9     9     0      0       1        0    14
10    10     1      0       0        0     3
11    11     0      0       0        1    18
12    12     0      1       0        0     5
13    13     0      1       0        0     9
14    14     0      0       0        1    16
15    15     0      1       0        0     6
16    16     0      0       0        1    15
17    17     0      0       1        0    12
18    18     0      0       1        0    10
19    19     0      0       0        1    20
20    20     0      1       0        0     8


You can use case_when() function from dplyr. This manually creates each dummy variable for the given ranges.
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    dummy_0_5 = case_when(value >= ranges[1] & value < ranges[2] ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    dummy_5_10 = case_when(value >= ranges[2] & value < ranges[3] ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    dummy_10_15 = case_when(value >= ranges[3] & value < ranges[4] ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)
  )

print(data)

However, if you want to generate the variables dynamically, (i.e.:automatically generating columns based on the ranges), here’s a scalable approach:
# Dynamic generation of dummy variables for ranges
data <- data %>%
  bind_cols(
    lapply(1:(length(ranges) - 1), function(i) {
      case_when(
        .$value >= ranges[i] & .$value < ranges[i + 1] ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0
      )
    }) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      setNames(paste0("dummy_", head(ranges, -1), "_", tail(ranges, -1)))
  )


I have followed these steps to achieve this:

create a new column which categorizes the numeric variable of interest. This variable will be then deselected and not shown in the final table
then use dummy_cols in the fastDummies library to get the dummy variables based on the new column
Then, create the column names with a for loop.

It is sufficient to change the values in ranges to have an automatic modification of the dummy variables and the column names. This solution should work even when changing the number of elements in ranges.
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:20, value = sample(20))
ranges <- c(0, 5, 10, 15)

# Using the current range, categorization has value
#  1: if the value is in range 0-5
#  2: if the value is in range 5-10
#  3: if the value is in range 10-15
#  4: if the value is in range 15-20
#  By changing the values in ranges, this adjusts automatically
data$categorization <- findInterval(data$value, ranges)

library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data %>%
  dummy_cols(select_columns = "categorization") %>%
  select(-categorization) # deselect the categorization variable

# create column names
dummynames <- c()
for (i in 1:(length(ranges)-1)) {
  name <- paste0(ranges[i], "-", ranges[i+1])
  dummynames <- c(dummynames, name)
}

# last column name if you want to have a "greater than last boundary"
dummynames <- c(dummynames, paste0(">", last(ranges)))

# attach new column names for dummy variables
colnames(data2) <- c("ID", "value", dummynames)

# final result
head(data2)

  ID value 0-5 5-10 10-15 >15
1  1     4   1    0     0   0
2  2     7   0    1     0   0
3  3     1   1    0     0   0
4  4     2   1    0     0   0
5  5    13   0    0     1   0
6  6    19   0    0     0   1


Note that running lapply for findInterval on a single vector isn't incorrect but is an odd choice and about 16 times slower than running it as intended - simply findInterval(data$value, ranges). This may be relevant if speed is of concern on larger datasets.

Thank you for your comment! You are right, I have edited the reply according to your suggestion.

You can try findInterval followed by pivot_wider, e.g.,
cols <- str_c("dummy_", first(ranges, -1), "_", last(ranges, -1))
data %>%
  mutate(idx = cols[findInterval(value, ranges)], indicator = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = idx, values_from = indicator, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-`NA`)

which gives
# A tibble: 20 × 5
      ID value dummy_0_5 dummy_5_10 dummy_10_15
   <int> <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1     4         1          0           0
 2     2     7         0          1           0
 3     3     1         1          0           0
 4     4     2         1          0           0
 5     5    13         0          0           1
 6     6    19         0          0           0
 7     7    11         0          0           1
 8     8    17         0          0           0
 9     9    14         0          0           1
10    10     3         1          0           0
11    11    18         0          0           0
12    12     5         0          1           0
13    13     9         0          1           0
14    14    16         0          0           0
15    15     6         0          1           0
16    16    15         0          0           0
17    17    12         0          0           1
18    18    10         0          0           1
19    19    20         0          0           0
20    20     8         0          1           0

